# Job Interview Question Using Trees Part 2

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, time-complexity, avl-tree

Continuing this question: [Job Interview Question Using Trees, What data to save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65368238/job-interview-question-using-trees-what-data-to-save#65378902)

Now, I am looking for an algorithm that does the following:

`IsWorstSince(d1,d2)`: check wither d2 is the day with most new infected people since d1. Return:

`false` if there is one day between both days such that the number of infected people in that day is bigger than d2.

`true`, If we can verify for sure that from all days between d1 and d2 (Not only those who were inserted) none has bigger number of infected people than d2.

`unknown`, if there is some data missing, For example if some days weren't inserted into the data structure.

**Time Complexity: O(log n)**

We can assume that d1<d2 and that both days do exist in the data structure.

---

I think this question is really related to the previous one. but not sure how to use it.

Note: In the previous one we implemented WorseBefore(d) that return the last day (between those which were inserted to the DS) before d which had more infected people than there is in day d.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very similar to the solution I posted to your first question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65378902

Let's assume we have the same data structure and auxiliary information as in the first question, and let's assume `d1 < d2`.

Let `x = Sick(d2)`, which we can find in O(log n) by searching for `d2` in the tree.

Now ask yourself: where in the tree are the nodes that are greater than `d1`?

1. The right subtree of `d1`. So if `maxRightSick(d1) > x`, return false, because then there is a day that is greater than `d1` but which is worse than `d2`.
2. Find the *next* successor of `d1`: traverse the tree upwards towards the root until you find a node (which could be `d1` itself) that is the left child of another node, and then select the parent of that node. For example, in [this image](https://i.ibb.co/ngj9c4D/Screen-Shot-2020-12-20-at-4-23-53-PM.png) (provided by the OP), the next successor of 0012 would be 0014, of 0014 would be 0023, and of 0038 would be 0039. Some nodes don't have a next successor, e.g. 0043 or 0039.

If the next successor of `d1` does not exist, return true, because in that case `maxRightSick(d1)` *must* be equal to `x` and `d2` is somewhere in the right subtree of `d1`.

Otherwise, return the boolean value of the condition `Sick(nextSuccessor) < x and maxRightSick(nextSuccessor) < x`, because iff the condition is satisfied, all nodes within the subtree of the next successor are not worse than `d2`.